# Customize SSRS Permissions Error Message

Tags: reporting-services, permissions, customization, message

Is it possible to customize the 
"User '......' does not have the required permissions." 
 
error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: http://localhost/reports (Do login with your Computer's username and password).
You should now be directed to the Home page of SQL Server Reporting Services here: http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx
From the Home page, click the Properties tab, then click New Role Assignment.
In the Group or user name textbox, add the 'domain & username' which was in the error message (you can find the domain and username for your computer in the rsAccessDenied error message).
Select all roles such as Browser, Content Manager, My Reports, Publisher, Report Builder, and then click OK.
Now, your domain and username should be assigned to the Roles that will give you access to deploy your reports to the Report Server.  If you're using  SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio to deploy your reports to your local reports server, you should now be able to access.
Hopefully, that helps you solve your Reports Server rsAccessDenied error message.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sreejesh. But that didn't answer the question. I was wondering if the error "User '......' does not have the required permissions." can be changed.. Hoping to hear something.